Is it true that there exist infinitely many prime numbers $p$ such that $p$ splits in $K/\Bbb{Q}$ but does not split in $L/\Bbb{Q}$?
Let $K$ and $L$ be a quadratic extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$. Suppose that $K \neq L$ as fields, that is, if we write $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D_1}), L=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D_2})$, $D_1/D_2 \notin {{\Bbb{Q}}^{\times}}^2$.
Is it true that there exist infinitely many prime numbers $p$ such that $p$ splits in $K/\Bbb{Q}$ but does not split in $L/\Bbb{Q}$?
My thought: Jokingly speaking, I guess this is true because the Chebotarev density theorem states 50% of $p$ split completely in $K$ and not in $L$, so 25% satisfy the condition.

See this question  Note that Chebotarev only applies to Galois extensions, and you didn't assume Galois in the problem statement.

Perhaps you mean $K\not\cong L?$ For example, there are three different fields in $\mathbb C$ that are isomorphic to $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2).$

I started to think about this before the edit, so I'll give an answer to the more general question, though it also applies to the updated question.
A prime $\mathfrak{p} \in \mathcal{P}_K$ splits completely in a finite extension $L/K$ if all inertia degrees and ramification indices are $1$, so  $\mathfrak{p} \mathcal{O}_L = \mathfrak{P}_1\dotsm \mathfrak{P}_{[L:K]}$ with distinct $\mathfrak{P}_i$; denote the set of completely split primes by $\mathcal{S}_{L/K}$. For subsets $A,B$ of some set $X$ we say $A \mathbin{\dot\subseteq} B$ if $A \subseteq B \cup \{a_1,\dots,a_k\}$ for finitely many $a_i \in A$.
Thm. Let $K \subseteq L,L'$ be finite Galois extensions of number fields. The following are equivalent:

$L \subseteq L'$;
$\mathcal{S}_{L/K} \supseteq \mathcal{S}_{L'/K}$;
$\mathcal{S}_{L/K} \mathbin{\dot\supseteq} \mathcal{S}_{L'/K}$.

The implications 1.$\Rightarrow$2.$\Rightarrow$3. are immediate, the interesting implication 3.$\Rightarrow$1. can be found in David A. Cox' Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$, Theorem 8.19. And you're correct, this uses Cebotarev's density theorem in a clever way. You can partially extend this to non-Galois extensions (Theorem 8.20 and the exercises in that section).
Now in your question you have two distinct quadratic extensions $K,L$ of $\mathbb{Q}$. These are Galois, so the theorem can be applied: $L \not\subseteq K$, hence $S_{L/\mathbb{Q}}$ does not contain $S_{K/\mathbb{Q}}$ even after adding finitely many elements. Thus there are infinitely many primes $p$ which split in $K$ but not in $L$.

Why $S_{L/\Bbb{Q}}$ cannot contain $S_{K/\Bbb{Q}}$ even after adding $\textbf{finitely}$ many elements  ?

@Poitou-Tate The negation of $A \dot\subseteq B$ is "whatever finite set of elements ${a_1,\dots,a_k}$ you add to $B$, $A$ will never be contained in $B \cup {a_1,\dots,a_k}$".

Thank you! This is the last theorem (Prop 13.9) in Neukirch's 'Algebraic number theory'! It seems Brauer was the first to come up with it

Given your restriction to quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$, we can reduce the question of $p$ splitting to modular congruences. In particular Let $d \neq 0,1$ be some (WLOG) squarefree integer, and $p$ some odd prime. Then by using by using Dedekind's Criterion in the number field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, we have the following:

$p$ splits $\iff (\frac{d}{p})=1$
$p$ ramifies $\iff (\frac{d}{p})=0$
$p$ is inert $\iff (\frac{d}{p})=-1$

I'm using the Legendre Symbol here. There are also results for the special case $p=2$ but these aren't needed.
What you are asking is therefore equivalent to asking "are there infinitely many primes for which $D_1$ is a quadratic residue but $D_2$ is not?" or better yet "are there infinitely many primes for which $(\frac{D_1}{p})=1$ and $(\frac{D_2}{p})\neq 1$?"
Suppose that $D_1=p_1p_2...p_m$. Then $(\frac{D_1}{p})=(\frac{p_1}{p})(\frac{p_2}{p})...(\frac{p_m}{p})$. We have a lot of control over each of these prodands. For an odd prime $p_i$, if we require that $p=1 \bmod 4$ then by quadratic reciprocity $(\frac{p_i}{p})=(\frac{p}{p_i})$, and so by choosing an appropriate value for $p \bmod p_i$ we can decide the value of $(\frac{p_i}{p})$. In the special case $p_i=2$, we can choose $p=1 \bmod 8$ if we want $(\frac{2}{p})=1$, or choose $p=5 \bmod 8$ if we want $(\frac{2}{p})=-1$. Note that both options are compatible with the earlier restriction that $p=1 \bmod 4$. By the Chinese remainder theorem there is a solution to whatever set of simultaneous congruences we choose. We have a similar situation for $D_2=q_1q_2...q_n$ too.
We now just have to cover a few different cases:

If $D_2$ is divisible by some prime that $D_1$ is not divisible by (say $q_1$ WLOG), then just make $(\frac{q_1}{p})=-1$ and set all the other Legendre symbols in the products for $(\frac{D_1}{p})$ and $(\frac{D_2}{p})$ to $1$.
If $D_1$ is divisible by some prime that $D_2$ is not divisible by (say $p_1$ WLOG), then ensure that exactly one of the $(\frac{q_j}{p})$ is $-1$ and the rest are $1$. Then if that $q_j$ divides $D_1$ we can also make $(\frac{p_1}{p})=-1$ and all the others just $1$, so that exactly two of the Legendre symbols in the product for $(\frac{D_1}{p})$ are $-1$. Otherwise, if $q_j$ doesn't appear in the factorisation of $D_1$ we can just make all of those Legendre symbols $1$.
If $D_1$ and $D_2$ are divisible by the exact same set of primes then this is a contradiction of $D_1 \neq D_2$

(This was slightly clunky but I needed to deal with the fact that there are potentially shared primes between all the $p_i$s and $q_j$s.)
So there is some modular congruence class (coprime to the modular base, whatever it ended up being) for which all the primes $p$ in that class must necessarily satisfy $(\frac{D_1}{p})=1$ and $(\frac{D_2}{p})=-1$. Thus by Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions there are infinitely many such primes.

Could you tell me the definition of $D_1$ and $D_2$ ?

They play the same role as your ones. I was able to say that without loss of generality they are squarefree integers because $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{\frac{{p_1}^{e_1}...{p_s}^{e_s}}{{q_1}^{f_1}...{q_t}^{f_t}}})=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{{p_1'}...{p_a'}{q_1'}...{q_b'}})$ where the $p_i'$ are all the primes appearing in the numerator with an odd power, and the $q_j'$ are all the primes appearing in the denominator with an odd power.

Thank you very much. Is the condition $D_1/D_2 \notin {{\Bbb{Q}}^{\times}}^2$ inevitable?

For $D_1,D_2$ squarefree integers $D_1/D_2 \in {{\Bbb{Q}}^{\times}}^2 \iff D_1=D_2$
